# Why can not import a subclass from main class in python

Tags: python, python-import

Hi in Selenium I want to import a child classes from library but I couldn't do it.
Below is totally fine;

```
from Selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

But why I can not do such:

```
from Selenium import webdriver
_WebDriverWait = webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait
_expected_conditions = webdriver.support.expected_conditions
```

The reason why I want to do this is in an editor, I am trying to supply a kind of sandbox environment and want user to be able to use all sub classes of pre-imported selenium. How can I achieve this import?

Answer (score 1):

The first one works and the second one doesn't because a path in the `from` part of an import statement works differently from a path in an ordinary reference.

In a `from` clause, Python is willing to follow a path through a directory structure even if not all the names in the path have previously been imported.  For an ordinary reference, it is not willing to do that.

In the words of [Real Python's article on the import system](https://realpython.com/python-import/), "In general, submodules and subpackages aren’t imported when you import a package."

Sometimes the `__init.py__` script for a package will import some or all of the package's contents for you, so you don't have to worry about it, but in this case, Selenium doesn't do that for the `support` package in the `__init.py__` script for the `webdriver` package.

So you can make references like those in the second case work by adding lines to import the `ui` and `expected_conditions` modules explicitly:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui, expected_conditions
_WebDriverWait = ui.WebDriverWait
_expected_conditions = expected_conditions
```

This can make code like that in the second case work, but you may not consider it much of an improvement over the code in the first case.

Comment: Your answer is useful to me,Thank you